# Whats wrong with this video embed code?

Tags: html, flash, video, embed, flowplayer

Following embed code is from http://hd.se/landskrona/2010/04/09/kunglig-glans-pa-idrottsgalan/ but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8. Firefox no problems.

Any recommendations for improvements?
Thanks for your time!

```
<object width="480px" height="294px" id="_36313041" data="http://hd.se/static/media/html/flash/video-3/flowplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="movie" value="http://hd.se/static/media/html/flash/video-3/flowplayer.swf" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"key":"$3fff7448b28a8cffc85","contextMenu":["hd.se videospelare 1.0"],"plugins":{"rtmp":{"url":"http://hd.se/static/media/html/flash/video-3/flowplayer.rtmp.swf"},"controls":{"height":24,"opacity":1,"all":false,"play":true,"time":true,"scrubber":true,"playlist":false,"mute":true,"volume":true,"fullscreen":true,"backgroundColor":"#222222","backgroundGradient":"none","buttonColor":"#7c7c7c","buttonOverColor":"#36558b","progressColor":"#7c7c7c","bufferColor":"#7c7c7c","timeColor":"#ffffff","durationColor":"#ffffff","timeBgColor":"#222222","scrubberHeightRatio":0.5,"scrubberBarHeightRatio":0.5,"volumeSliderHeightRatio":0.5,"volumeBarHeightRatio":0.5,"autoHide":"fullscreen","hideDelay":1800,"tooltips":{"buttons":true,"play":"Spela","pause":"Paus","next":"Nästa","previous":"Föregående","mute":"Ljud av","unmute":"Ljud på","fullscreen":"Fullskärmsläge","fullscreenExit":"Lämna fullskärmsläge"},"tooltipColor":"#153872","tooltipTextColor":"#ffffff"},"contentIntro":{"url":"http://hd.se/static/media/html/flash/video-3/flowplayer.content.swf","top":0,"width":736,"border":"none","backgroundColor":"#202020","backgroundGradient":"none","borderRadius":"none","opacity":"85pct","display":"none","closeButton":true}},"canvas":{"backgroundColor":"#000000","backgroundGradient":"none"},"play":{"replayLabel":"Spela igen"},"screen":{"bottom":24},"clip":{"scaling":"fit","autoPlay":true},"playlist":[{"provider":"rtmp","netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://fl0.c06062.cdn.qbrick.com/06062","url":"ncode/hdstart","autoPlay":false,"scaling":"fit"},{"url":"http://hd.se/multimedia/archive/00425/_kunligglans_HD_VP6_425359a.flv","scaling":"fit","autoPlay":true},{"provider":"rtmp","netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://fl0.c06062.cdn.qbrick.com/06062","url":"ncode/hdstopp","autoPlay":true,"scaling":"fit"}]}' />
</object>
```

***UPDATE 2010-05-14:***

If I'm not mistaken HD.se uses **Flowplayer** and all those flasvars are for that. Perhaps someone here is good with **Flowplayer**? I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have 'px' in the `width` and `height` attributes, only a number. Also IDs cannot start with an underscore, they can only start with a letter.

So your code should start `<object width="480" height="294" id="f_36313041"`. However, if the ID is used for anything you may have to change external code somewhere.

Have you double-checked the value of "flashvars" too? It's an incredibly long and complex string so there could easily be an error there somewhere.

Comment: I've tried to remove px and also id but still wont work in IE.
Its not my website, but i need to embed the video on my website. 
But when you look at forexample YouTubes embed code it also have embed-tag, is that perhaps why it wont work in IE? 
Doesn't IE use embed-tag whilst Firefox use object and param tags?

Comment: No, IE doesn't need embed tags at all, that's an old Netscape thing IIRC. IE does need the "movie" parameter, which you have added.

Comment: On further thought... since that site is the one giving you bad code, maybe you should try and take it up with them if you can? I'm sure they want their embed code to work in all browsers!

Comment: Yeah will do that, but still would like to know what is wrong and how to fix it :) When i use that embed code in IE it's just blank, all white. If I right click it do get the Flash menu but no video is ever loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create object/embed tags directly to embed Flash.  Always use an external JS file to generate the required tags.  `SWFObject` is the most widely used one.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWFObject

Info on why you want to use an external JS file:

http://blog.deconcept.com/2005/12/15/internet-explorer-eolas-changes-and-the-flash-plugin/

Comment: What http://blog.deconcept.com/2005/12/15/internet-explorer-eolas-changes-and-the-flash-plugin/ says is not the case in IE8 anymore if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @jamietelin, I wasn't sure, but I couldn't find a definitive reference either way.  Can you?  Regardless, using `SWFObject` is still better.